# Why facebook tries to send POST request when I open my application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I've just register my application on facebook. When I try to open up it via browser like http://apps.facebook.com/myapplication/ I get the error:

```
Cannot POST /
```

I've looked into my iframe parameters and saw that one iframe above send POST request with hidden field signed_request. What it is?

Comment: _“What it is?”_ – this is _how it works_.

Answer (score 0):

You question is much related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050230/why-is-the-first-request-to-a-facebook-iframe-app-canvas-page-a-post-request) , facebook needs to send signed_request to your application with authentication user information.

The error you met is because your application does not support post method to routing '/'